# How do I find out the position of a widget to draw a rectangle?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I've added a bunch of widgets and sub-widgets to my kivy app.

Now I want to draw a rectangle on some particular `Label()` called `my_label`

```
with my_label.canvas.before:
  Color(0, random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
  my_label.rect = Rectangle(
    size=[100, 70],
    pos=[110, 35]
  )
```

Instead of `[110, 35]`, I'd like to position the rectangle on `my_label`.  But `my_label.pos == [0, 0]`.  How do I find out
where `my_label` is relative to the root so I can set the rectangle's `pos` correctly?

Using `mylabel.canvas.after` doesn't seem to change this.

This label is added dynamically, so I can't depend on setting it up right in `kv`.

Comment: can you just use `self.size` and `self.pos`? That's what I use in my kv files.

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing code is running before the label pos has been set by its parent layout - basically you're hitting the issue that your rectangle position doesn't update when the label position later does.

To fix this you should make a binding to move the rectangle when necessary, such as:

```
my_label.bind(pos=self.update_rect)
```

and a new method:

```
def update_rect(self, label, new_pos):
    label.rect.pos = label.pos
```

You can also do the same for the size if necessary.

If you draw the rectangle in kv instead, these bindings are created automatically.